# Newly installed apps don't show up in dash

Tags: unity-dash

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, it seems newly installed applications do not show up in dash.

Some do once I've launched them manually via terminal, others like mysql-workbench don't show up at all.

Comment: New applications with `.desktop` files show up next time you log in.

Comment: Really, on the next login? Is that a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't a bug. The dash has a cache of apps, it doesn't show new ones right away.

Try opening, closing, and opening the dash again. This has worked for me. A logout will do the trick too, but I think it's a bit overkill.

Opening the dash the first time will start refreshing it's cache, but it won't show the update while it is open. So closing and reopening it will then have its app cache updated.

Note that your programs do need to have a `.desktop` file somewhere in the many variations of "applications" folders. If there isn't a `.desktop` file associated with the program, it will never show up in the dash.